Why these two representations are equivalent?
Assume that $\sigma :G\to GL(A)$ by $\sigma_f (\alpha)(=f\cdot \alpha)$ is a representation of a group $G$ in a finite dimensional real vector space $V$. We can define a representation $\sigma^* :G\to GL(A^*)$ by $\sigma^*_f (p)(=f\cdot p)=p\circ \sigma^{-1}_{f}$. We have a biliniear  pairing $\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle :A^* \times A\to \mathbb{R}$ by $\langle p,\alpha \rangle =p(\alpha)$. Then we can show that $\langle f\cdot p,f\cdot \alpha \rangle =\langle p,\alpha \rangle$. Since $A$ is finite dimensional, the pairing defines a non-degenerate bilinear form
$(\cdot ,\cdot )$ on $A$. So there exists an isomorphism $T:A\to A^* :\alpha \to (\alpha ,\cdot )$.  Now
I want to show that for all $f\in G$, $\sigma^*_f =T\circ \sigma_f\circ T^{-1}$ but I coudn't.

In this situation, you don't actually have a pairing on $A$, as your domain is $A^*\times A$, which is why you only get a morphism $A\rightarrow A^{**}=A$, which turns out to be the identity.
